# Debug ultisnip snippet

Tags: normal-mode, plugin-ultisnips

I have ultisnips installed and when I type `ve` in normal mode it changes the word. Let's say I have:

word

When I type `ve` to select until the end of the word it does the following

[image: asciicast]

Plese also help me with the proper tag for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to [debug your vimrc file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file)?

If the issue is narrowed down to this plugin, the [plugin-ultisnips](/questions/tagged/plugin-ultisnips) tag would be relevant.

Otherwise, you should post the problematic part of your configuration here.

Edit: what does `:nmap ve` output?

Comment: Dispite v being a key for visual I have already tryied :verbose nmap ve

Comment: Maybe start with `vim -V` to see what happens under the hood.